# Как гарантировать очередность обработки сообщений из rabbitmq

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq

Есть сервис A, который при изменении сущностей отправляет их через RabbitMQ в сервис B. Сервис B развернут на 4х нодах.

Задача - гарантированно обрабатывать очередность изменений сущности с одинаковым идентификатором.

Сейчас получается такая ситуация - изменяется сущность с ID 1 множество раз, но так как слушателей в сервисе B много, то сообщения обрабатываются не в том порядке, в котором менялась сущность с ID 1.

Так же есть проблема в том, что сервис A может быть развернут на нескольких нодах. Изменение сущности с ID 1 может произойти на разных нодах, из-за этого нет гарантии, что в RabbitMq положаться сообщения не в гарантированном порядке изменения.

Какие практики решают и эту проблему?

Стек - java, spring

Comment: Какова природа событий изменений сущностей?
Может быть их есть смысл объединить эти события в одно, содержащее сортированный список?

Comment: Подобные вещи решаются архитектурныйм образом, с помощью добавление некой логики, которая "отслеживает" порядок обработки сообщения. В случае интереса - могу более подробно расписать в ответе, но это займет некоторое время.